# Angular not updating view after data has been updated

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

I have two components. One for creating and one for listing data that is stored in a database.
The problem is that when I create a new one that gets stored in the database I try tell the "lister" to update its view so it can show what just has been added. The weird thing is that it dose not show up, even tho I see the data it self has been updated and loaded from the databse, but not shown the view for the component.
Have stripped down the code a bit here.

The "Maker"

```
import { Component, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { DataRestaurant } from '../../shared/data/restaurant';

import { ModulesRestaurants } from './restaurants.moldule';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-module-make-restaurant',
  templateUrl: './make.restaurant.module.html',
  providers: [ModulesRestaurants]
})
export class ModulesMakeRestaurant {

  @Input() restaurantData = { name: '', description: '' };
  restaurant: DataRestaurant;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private translate: TranslateService, private restLister: ModulesRestaurants) {
       translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurant = new DataRestaurant;
  }


  // Create restaurant - used by the button the makes the new data
  createRestaurant() {
    this.dataService.createRestaurant(this.restaurantData).subscribe(data => {
      this.restLister.refresh();  //Calls the 'refresh' in the lister
    });
  }
}
```

The "Lister"

```
import { Component, Inject, Input, Injectable, ViewChild, ApplicationRef  } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { DataRestaurant } from '../../shared/data/restaurant';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-module-restaurants',
  templateUrl: './restaurants.module.html'
})


export class ModulesRestaurants {

  @Input() restaurantData = { name: '', description: '', };

  DataRestaurants: any = [];


  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private translate: TranslateService private appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAll();

  }


  refresh() {
    this.getAll();
    this.appRef.tick();

  }

  // Get all restaurants
  getAll() {
    return this.dataService.getAllRestaurants().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.DataRestaurants = data;
      console.log(this.DataRestaurants);
    })
  }



  trackData(index: number, item: DataRestaurant) {
    return this.DataRestaurants ? this.DataRestaurants : undefined;
  }

}
```

DB Sevice

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataRestaurant } from '../app/shared/data/restaurant';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Guid } from "guid-typescript";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private REST_API_SERVER = "https://localhost:44377/api";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  // Http Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  } 


  ////RESTAURANTS
  //HttpClient API post() method => Get all restaurants
  getAllRestaurants(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<DataRestaurant[]>(this.REST_API_SERVER + '/restaurant/GetAll')
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError<DataRestaurant[]>('getAllRestaurants'))
      )
  }

  // HttpClient API post() method => Create restaurant
  createRestaurant(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<DataRestaurant>(this.REST_API_SERVER + '/restaurant/Create', JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError<DataRestaurant>('createRestaurants'))
      )
  }

    // HttpClient API delete() method => Delete restaurant
  deleteRestaurant(id): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete<DataRestaurant>(this.REST_API_SERVER + '/restaurant/Delete/' + id, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError<DataRestaurant>('deleteRestaurant'))
      )
  }

  // Error handling
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
    
      console.error(error);

      return throwError(result as T);
    };
  }


}
```

HTML Lister

```
  <ng-container>
      <table>
        <thead class="text-primary">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">{{ 'restaurants.name' | translate }}</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody">
          <tr *ngFor="let data of DataRestaurants; let i = index; trackBy: trackData" >
            <td>
              <input type="text"
                     [(ngModel)]="data.name"
                     class="form-control"
                     placeholder="Name"
                     style="outline:none;">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="update">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-round" (click)="getAll()"> Refresh </button>
        </div>
      </div>

  </ng-container>
```

Like I mentioned the `refresh()` works and get called from the "maker". I can even see the `this.DataRestaurants` has been updated with the new data. But its not updated in the view.

UPDATE:
After doing some more debugging, I have come the conclusion it seems like there are two instances of the same data. One that is shown, and one that is used by the 'refresh' call from the maker. Isn't `[providers]` running on the same thread as it has been initialized from?

Anyone who has any suggestions here?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with your `trackBy` function. Do you really need it? If you are really stuck and can't get the binding to update, you could inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component and call the `DetectChanges` method after assigning the field. But that should indeed be a last resort.

Comment: It seems more to have something to do with instances as after some more debugging with before and after checks of the data that should be updated. I can see that the Maker `getAll()` data differs from if `getAll()` is run on the Lister.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Lister component should only receive the restaurant data. That gives a nice smart - dumb component structure and remove unnecessary injections.

Parent component

```
refresh$ = new Subject(); // a button can call refresh$.next() and it will retrieve the data again
restaurantData$ = this.getAll();

getAll() {
 return this.refresh$.pipe(
   startWith(<unknown>null),
   switchMap(()=> this.dataService.getAllRestaurants())
 );
```

}

And in the template use restaurantData$| async